# Viewing issue in UIScrollVieiw

Tags: ios, button, view, uiscrollview

I need to stack up say 20 buttons in the scroll view. I did manage to
add them all. It was a headache, cause I am not well versed with the auto
layout. Now when I ran the app in the simulator, I am not able to
scroll fully i.e the view bounces and hides a lot of buttons from being
accessed.

Can someone guide me in a simple way, the implementation of the same?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you didn't set content to the scrollView.

Try [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mws6Zbq_y6c) tutorial, really helped me when I implemented a Scroll View for the first time.

Comment: sorry for that. I can't access youtube here. I'll check later and say. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> I found this answer in one of the stackoverflow post:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
self.yourscrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x,y);
```

}

> Adding this to the scroll view and edit the values x,y will let you control
>   the amount you can scroll :)